# django form is invalid, but no error messages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following form:

```
class SkuForm(forms.Form):
  base_item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=BaseItem.objects.none())
  color_or_print = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Color.objects.none())
  material = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Material.objects.none())
  size_group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Size_Group.objects.none())
```

my view:

```
def sku_builder(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    user = request.user
    form = SkuForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        base_item = form.cleaned_data['base_item']
        colors = filter(lambda t: t[0] in form.cleaned_data['color_or_print'], form.fields['color_or_print'].choices)
        materials = filter(lambda t: t[0] in form.cleaned_data['material'], form.fields['material'].choices)
        size_groups = filter(lambda t: t[0] in form.cleaned_data['size_group'], form.fields['size_group'].choices)
        return render(request, 'no_entiendo.html', {'colors': colors, })
    else:
        return HttpResponse("form is not valid")
user = request.user
form = SkuForm()
form.fields['base_item'].queryset = BaseItem.objects.filter(designer=user)
form.fields['color_or_print'].queryset = Color.objects.filter(designer=user)
form.fields['material'].queryset = Material.objects.filter(designer=user)
form.fields['size_group'].queryset = Size_Group.objects.filter(designer=user)
return render(request, 'Disenador/sku_builder.html', {'form': form,})
```

The problem is that Im only receiving the "form is not valid message" I have no idea why it is not valid as the Form is only made of choices, so no typo error. Also I have no feedback from the system to debug, or don't know where to search.

*what happens after form.is_valid is not the complete code

UPDATE: 
I placed the {{ form.errors}} and got this:
color_or_print

```
Select a valid choice. 6 is not one of the available choices.
```

base_item

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

size_group

```
Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices.
```

In size_group and  color_or_print the number is the pk (but is only showing one item, 2 were selected), not sure what is happening in base_item. Should I extract the values through a:

```
get_object_or_404 ?
```

and what can I do with base_item? here is an image of the information
[posted from the debug_toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wYKt.png)

Comment: Instead of sending HttpReponse in case of invalid form, render the html with the form and errors.

Comment: thank you, I did that, still no clear route of action.

Comment: You need to define your field querysets in `SkuForm`'s init method

Comment: its working now, can you explain me when it is recommended to set the fields on the view, if its not the best, why is it allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending an `HttpResponse`, you need to render the html with the form if the form is invalid.

```
if form.is_valid():
    # Do your operations on the data here
    ...
    return render(request, 'no_entiendo.html', {'colors': colors, })
else:
    return render(request, 'Disenador/sku_builder.html', {'form': form,})
```

Also if you're using model choice fields, the ideal place to define your queryset is in your form's `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    self.fields['base_item'].queryset = BaseItem.objects.filter(designer=user)
    # define more querysets here as you require
    ...
    super(SkuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can change the queryset in view. But that as far as I understand is a way to override whatever you have set in your forms. It should normally be set in `__init__`.

Comment: If you try to access self.fields before calling "super", won't this give an exception? Are the fields in existence at this point?

Answer (score 0):

try to render {{form.errors}} in your template

Comment: Thanks! This is the key that errors locate. It's html format, but good enough to show the errors even without rendering.